# Showing that the weak law of large numbers does not hold for some sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with the following distribution:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=n)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},\quad \mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\quad\text{for any}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

My question is how to show that the weak law of large numbers **does not hold** for such a sequence? I am only able to prove that the strong law of large numbers fails to hold (by using Borel-Cantelli Lemma). But I have no idea how to proceed with the WLLN, even though I have tried many times. I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: *Hint*: Let $\varphi_n(t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(itX_n)]$ be the characteristic function of $X_n$, and let $\psi_n(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi_k(t/n)$.  Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\psi_n(t)$ is not the constant $1$ (so the limiting distribution $\bar{X}_n$ does not degenerate, i.e., WLLN fails).